Crash when creating QT QList
I am trying to create a simple QT QList of type QLine, but every time I compile & run it on Windows I get an exception: 
The call stack is:
>   basic_example.exe!QArrayDataPointer<QLine>::~QArrayDataPointer<QLine>() Line 112    C++ 
    basic_example.exe!QArrayDataPointer<QLine>::reallocateAndGrow(QArrayData::GrowthPosition where, __int64 n, QArrayDataPointer<QLine> * old) Line 250 C++ 
    basic_example.exe!QArrayDataPointer<QLine>::detachAndGrow(QArrayData::GrowthPosition where, __int64 n, const QLine * * data, QArrayDataPointer<QLine> *old) Line 210    C++ 
    basic_example.exe!QtPrivate::QPodArrayOps<QLine>::emplace<QLine const &>(__int64 i, const QLine & <args_0>) Line 179    C++ 
    basic_example.exe!QList<QLine>::emplaceBack<QLine const &>(const QLine & <args_0>) Line 886 C++ 
    basic_example.exe!QList<QLine>::append(const QLine & t) Line 459    C++

The code is in the drawBackground function of a QGraphicsScene.
Below is a minimum viable program that can re-create the issue I am having, I don't believe I am doing anything out of the ordinary.
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>
#include<QtWidgets/qgraphicsview.h>
#include<QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
#include<QtWidgets/qboxlayout.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qgraphicsscene.h>
#include <QtGui/qpainter.h>

class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene {
public:
    GraphicsScene (QGraphicsScene* parent = nullptr) : QGraphicsScene (parent) {
        int scene_width = 64000;
        int scene_height = 64000;

        // Set the focus to be in the middle of the view when it's created.
        setSceneRect (-scene_width / 2,
            -scene_width / 2,
            scene_width,
            scene_height);
    };

private:
    void drawBackground (QPainter* painter, const QRectF& rect) {
        QGraphicsScene::drawBackground (painter, rect);

        QList<QLine> lines;
        QLine line_that_crashes = QLine (0, 0, 100, 100);
        lines.append (line_that_crashes);
    }
};

class Window : public QWidget {
public:
    Window (QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QWidget (parent) {
        setGeometry (200, 200, 1024, 768);
        setWindowTitle ("Minimum Window");

        layout_ = new QVBoxLayout ();
        layout_->setContentsMargins (0, 0, 0, 0);
        setLayout (layout_);

        graphics_scene_ = new GraphicsScene ();
        view_ = new QGraphicsView (this);
        view_->setScene (graphics_scene_);
        layout_->addWidget (view_);

        show ();
    }

private:
    QGraphicsScene* graphics_scene_;
    QBoxLayout* layout_;
    QGraphicsView* view_;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication application(argc, argv);

    Window wnd;

    return application.exec();
}

Debug : 

You need to post minimal-reproducible-example. Your application doesn't throw std::exception, it just crashes, probably because you have a bug (possibly UB ) somewhere else.

Or if you don't have the motivation to narrow down the problem to MRE, then you can try to use your debugger to investigate the stacktrace, and/or use Address Sanitizers. But I see that you are on windows, so already in a disadvantage.

Note that heap corruption typically manifests the first time you allocate or free memory, which may not be close (either in time or in code) to the place that corrupted memory earlier. There is nothing wrong with your use of QList or QLine.

Run you application form debugger. THen when this window pops up, press: "Retry". Debugger should kick in. Find in Debugger window called "call stack" and click through each entry reviewing local variables. Line you are pointing as a problem is perfectly fine. Problem is different place.

@pptaszni Apologies for what I thought the code snippets were okay for what I was asking. I have updated to include a minimum reproducible example.

Sorry, cannot reproduce the crash on my machine, address sanitizer, gdb, or valgrind doesn't show anything wrong, and the code in principle looks OK to me. Note that in your example you don't need to keep the pointers to graphics_scene_, layout_ and view_

Looks like you have heap corrupted and this error surfaces on destruction of QList<QLine> lines; - this part of code is valid without doubt. My recommendation is to enable address sanitizer (MSVC supports it now), so heap corruption is catch early. Since you are using Qt most probably you are suing CMake.

This is a result of mixing debug and release binaries, Qt is using different heaps for allocation and deallocation.
Qt Release binaries should be linked with your application only in release mode, and a Debug build should only link debug binaries of Qt. Don't mix debug and release binaries
CMake should handle this on its own and link the correct versions, also QtCreator can generate proper CMake files that you can use in other IDEs, avoid linking things manually and use a proper build system.

Thank you, I feel very stupid missing such a simple mistake

What was the clue which give you a hint this is a problem? I do not see anything in question which suggest problem is build process.

@MarekR i have seen it before like 2 times, though the last one was with QCharts, seeing it in QList is new to me, it is clear that it is a CRT mismatch anyway.

Ok so no actual clue in question, just by own experience with mysterious crashes. I was hoping that I will learn some new way of diagnosing problems.

It seems to be a double deletion of the same pointer, and the root cause is in this line:
view_ = new QGraphicsView(this);

Here you create an object view_ and set its parent, however later you also add this object to the layout: layout_->addWidget(view_);. When your Window destroys, it deletes the layout, and the view, but layout also tries to delete the same view as its own child. To fix this, just create your view like:
view_ = new QGraphicsView;


Still getting a crash with the change. The crash happens in ~QArrayDataPointer() when I leave the drawBackground function.

Qt implementation protects it from this kind of scenario. Whenever QObject is destroyed, it removes itself from its parent children list, so there is no double free in this scenario. Also QLayout https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#addItem takes the ownership of the item, changing the parent (not 100% about this last point, looking at the impl).
